# JSON Pagination - hibernate, spring

Tags: json, hibernate

I'm new to JSON and hibernate. I believe I know how to do pagination in hibernate, but not sure how to display the data with page information using JSON. 
I would like to have the output in the following format:

```
{
"page" : 1,
"pagesize" : 10,
"pagecount" : 3,
"models" : [{"id":1, "name":"text1"}, {"id":2, "name":"text2"}, {"id":3, "name":"text3"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring will convert your modelMap into JSON using whatever data you pass into it.  So if you invoked this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView sample() {
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.put("foo", "bar");
    return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
}
```

you would get this in the response:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Set your model up correctly in the controller and let Spring take care of the rest.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for your response. But, what I'm looking for is, I want to know how to show meta data information like Page Number, Page Size etc. with Entity Model using Spring. Pls. let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Add them to the model explicitly.

Comment: I don't know how to add them explicitly. Could you please provide me one example. Thanks.